# How do I convert Doctrine Annotation Information To Array?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, annotations, doctrine, symfony

I have the following inventory entity object for Doctrine that I created for use in Symfony 3.0.

Simply put how do I get access to the information that I put in the entity via annotations?

For example, companyID, has a ManyToOne annotation that references inversedBy="location".  This particular information is very useful to me so I can tell if its a child relationship by foreign key or parent relationship.

If I can get the information about the entity that I described via annotations somehow in an array with Doctrine that would be great.  Is this possible to do? Essentially I'm looking for introspection functions on the entity.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Inventory
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="distribution_inventory")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\InventoryRepository")
 */
class Inventory implements Translatable {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

     /**
     * @var string
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name","id"},suffix=".html")
     * @ORM\Column(name="inventoryslug", type="string", length=255, nullable=false, nullable=true)
     */
    private $inventoryslug;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="barcode", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $barcode;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

     /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="imagename", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $imagename;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Locale
     * Used locale to override Translation listener`s locale
     * this is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property
     */
    private $locale;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\InventoryCategory
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\InventoryCategory")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoryid", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Company
     * @Assert\Type(type="\AppBundle\Entity\Company")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Company", inversedBy="Location")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="companyid", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $companyId;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $created
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $updated
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="defaultsellprice",precision=14, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $defaultsellprice;



     /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="onwaycount", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
     private $onwaycount;

      /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="instorecount", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
     private $instorecount;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="wayoutcount", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
     private $wayoutcount;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="instore", type="string", length=10, nullable=false)
     */
     private $instore;

      /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isarchived", type="string", length=5, nullable=false,options={"default":false})
     */
     private $isarchived;

     /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="archivestatus", type="string", length=5, nullable=false,options={"default":true})
     */
     private $archivestatus;


     function __construct() {
         $this->onwaycount=0;
         $this->instore=FALSE;
         $this->instorecount=0;
         $this->wayoutcount=0;
     }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Inventory
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set barcode
     *
     * @param string $barcode
     *
     * @return Inventory
     */
    public function setBarcode($barcode) {
        $this->barcode = $barcode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get barcode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBarcode() {
        return $this->barcode;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Inventory
     */
    public function setDescription($description) {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }
    public function getImagename() {
        return $this->imagename;
    }

    public function getCategory() {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function getCompanyId() {
        return $this->companyId;
    }

    public function getCreated() {
        return $this->created;
    }

    public function getUpdated() {
        return $this->updated;
    }

    public function getOnwaycount() {
        return $this->onwaycount;
    }

    public function getInstorecount() {
        return $this->instorecount;
    }

    public function getWayoutcount() {
        return $this->wayoutcount;
    }

    public function getInstore() {
        return $this->instore;
    }

    public function setImagename($imagename) {
        $this->imagename = $imagename;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setCategory(\AppBundle\Entity\InventoryCategory $category) {
        $this->category = $category;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setCompanyId(\AppBundle\Entity\Company $companyId) {
        $this->companyId = $companyId;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setCreated(\DateTime $created) {
        $this->created = $created;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setUpdated(\DateTime $updated) {
        $this->updated = $updated;
        return $this;
    }


    public function setOnwaycount($onwaycount) {
        $this->onwaycount = $onwaycount;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setInstorecount($instorecount) {
        $this->instorecount = $instorecount;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setWayoutcount($wayoutcount) {
        $this->wayoutcount = $wayoutcount;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setInstore($instore) {
        $this->instore = $instore;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDefaultsellprice() {
        return $this->defaultsellprice;
    }

    public function setDefaultsellprice($defaultsellprice) {
        $this->defaultsellprice = $defaultsellprice;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getInventoryslug() {
        return $this->inventoryslug;
    }

    public function setInventoryslug($inventoryslug) {
        $this->inventoryslug = $inventoryslug;
        return $this;
    }



    public function setTranslatableLocale($locale) {
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }

    public function getIsarchived() {
        return $this->isarchived;
    }

    public function getArchivestatus() {
        return $this->archivestatus;
    }

    public function setIsarchived($isarchived) {
        $this->isarchived = $isarchived;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setArchivestatus($archivestatus) {
        $this->archivestatus = $archivestatus;
        return $this;
    }



}
```

Found this not sure if it will help though (http://tocacar.com/2013/01/25/doctrine2-object-introspection/)

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Doctrine AnnotationReader class](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.2/class-Doctrine.Common.Annotations.AnnotationReader.html)

Comment: I found this recently too (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/metadata-drivers.html), I think it might be what I need but not sure yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an array of metadata:

```
$cmf = $em->getMetadataFactory();
$metadata = $cmf->getMetadataFor(\AppBundle\Entity\Inventory::class);
//Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata instance
//as array:
$metadata = (array) $metadata;
```

To get the inversed information:

```
$metadata->getAssociationMapping('companyId')['inversedBy'];
//as array
$metadata['associationMappings']['companyId']['inversedBy'];
```

You can find more info [on the docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/metadata-drivers.html).